# Removing all the observations except for observations from day 10 or day 20

Tags: r

I want to remove all the observations except for observations from day 10 or day 20 from data(ChickWeight). But I want to use logical operations in r : and "&" or :|. Below is my code but i get an error

```
ChickWeight %>% slice(10|20)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could concatenate (`c`) the indexes as a `vector` and use `-` to remove the observations in `slice` - `slice` requires numeric index

```
library(dplyr)
ChickWeight %>%
   slice(-c(10, 20))
```

With `filter`, it expects a logical vector

```
ChickWeight %>% 
   filter(!row_number() %in% c(10, 20))
```

---

If this is based on the 'Time' column, use either of the one below

```
ChickWeight %>%
   slice(-which(Time %in% c(10, 20)))
ChickWeight %>% 
   filter(! Time %in% c(10, 20))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `filter`:

```
ChickWeight %>%
  filter(row_number() != 10 &
           row_number() != 20)

# A tibble: 576 × 4
   weight  Time Chick Diet 
    <dbl> <dbl> <ord> <fct>
 1     42     0 1     1    
 2     51     2 1     1    
 3     59     4 1     1    
 4     64     6 1     1    
 5     76     8 1     1    
 6     93    10 1     1    
 7    106    12 1     1    
 8    125    14 1     1    
 9    149    16 1     1    
10    199    20 1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subset`,

```
ChickWeight |> subset(Time == 10 | Time == 20)
```

or `with` (same result)

```
ChickWeight[with(ChickWeight, Time == 10 | Time == 20), ]
#     weight Time Chick Diet
# 6       93   10     1    1
# 11     199   20     1    1
# 18     103   10     2    1
# 23     209   20     2    1
# 30      99   10     3    1
# 35     198   20     3    1
# ...
```

or likewise a `seq`uence if you aim for row numbers.

```
ChickWeight |> subset({m <- seq_len(nrow(ChickWeight)); m == 10 | m == 20})
    
ChickWeight[{m <- seq_len(nrow(ChickWeight)); m == 10 | m == 20}, ]
#    weight Time Chick Diet
# 10    171   18     1    1
# 20    138   14     2    1
```